# Form api AJAX, reload js in #attached 3 times

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I have a simple form api ajax which does nothing special. In the form I have a js file:

```
 $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'commerce/cart';
```

In the js file I put a log console:

```
function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cart = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      console.log('aaaa');
  }
});
```

The log console prints 3 times: "aaaa" after the ajax action is over.
As if the file was loaded 3 times.
If you load the page normally, without ajax, the script runs one time

Comment: As mentioned below, you have to add core/jquery.once dependency to your library and use it as written below. Although now you have to use each(), the code below is d7.

Comment: @IvanJaros It's D8 code, it's actually copied from the linked docs

Comment: OK, I have never used once for chaining, but just fyi https://www.drupal.org/node/2457769

Comment: @IvanJaros The canonical example from the library itself is: `$('p').once('changecolor').css('color', 'red');` The Drupal docs are accurate, they mention the chaining specifically: _Moves towards jQuery chaining rather than function callbacks_. `each()` is only useful/required when you want to execute an arbitrary function on all the matched elements. It's not necessary if you just want to execute a jQuery method on them, as `once` returns the collection as normal

Comment: yeah i get it, just sayin' i have never, ever, encountered such case :D

Answer (score 2):

> The log console prints 3 times: "aaaa" after the ajax action is over

That's correct, behaviours are re-attached after AJAX requests. That's actually the point of them - to ensure that Drupal modules can respond to changes in the DOM.

If you want to limit the effect of that, core provides `once()`. You'll need to add the once library separately, after which you can use, for example:

```
$(context)
  .find('input.myCustomBehavior')
  .once('myCustomBehavior')
  .addClass('processed');
```

See the [JavaScript API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) for more information.

Of course you don't have to use `once`, if you don't need the complexity it offers you can just keep track of a boolean that determines whether or not your code should execute again.